# How to extract consecutive even numbers from a list?

Tags: python

In a list, a minimum of 2 even numbers makes a sequence: for example, a list that is `[3, 18, 6, 5, 3, 4, 32, 8, 12]` has 2 sequences that are even - which are `18, 6` and `4, 32, 8, 12`.

How do I extract the sequences without extracting every even number individually?

```
def saisie():
    test = False
    while not test:
        N = int(input("donner N: "))
        test = 3<=N<=20
    return N

def remplir(N):
    t=[int]*N
    for i in range(N):
        element = input("enter an element:")
        t.append(element)
    return t

def seq(N, t):
    s=""
    for i in t:
        if t[i] and t[i+=]%2==0:
            s=
```

Comment: In English, *even* is more commonly used that *pair*... I have just done the edit.

Comment: could you explain the purpose of remplir(N) and your test loop? i believe the latter is aimed to test the length of the input?

Comment: im supposed to make a list with an N number and then fill the list with numbers that the user chooses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To group items with shared criteria, you can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

nums = [3, 18, 6, 5, 3, 4, 32, 8, 12]

for is_even, grouper in groupby(nums, key=lambda x: x % 2 == 0):
    if is_even:
        evens = list(grouper)  # grouper objects have no len. Must convert to list
        if len(evens) >= 2:  # only consider sequences of at least 2 even numbers
            print(*evens)
```

Will give:

```
18 6
4 32 8 12
```